# Lost characters when typing with keyboard Vietnamese on javafx ios gluon app

Tags: ios, mobile, unicode, keyboard, gluon

Use:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
    <javafx.version>21</javafx.version>
    <attach.version>4.0.19</attach.version>
    <gluonfx.plugin.version>1.0.21</gluonfx.plugin.version>
    <javafx.plugin.version>0.0.8</javafx.plugin.version>
    <mainClassName>com.gluonapplication.GluonApplication</mainClassName>
</properties>
```

No lost characters when typing with keyboard Vietnamese on javafx ios gluon app

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When I use gluon version 1.0.21, javafx 21 creates ios app, there is a problem typing text in the textfield with the Vietnamese keyboard, for example typing "tai" with an acute but only view “tá" should appear is "tái"

Comment: When I use gluon version 1.0.21, javafx 21 creates ios app, there is a problem typing text in the textfield with the Vietnamese keyboard, for example typing "tai" with after an character “s” but only view “tá" should appear is "tái